# TTML styles missing

Tags: html, css, html5-video, microsoft-edge, ttml

I've created static *.html5 file and deployed it on wildfly 8.1.0. Inside I've created  tag with TTML subtitles. When I open page in IE Edge, subtitles are rendered but my css settings are not shown. Only setting that is working is region. How can I make my styles work? 
This is example of my subtitles track:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tt
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml"
    xmlns:ttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#parameter"
    xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling" ttp:timeBase="media" xml:lang="eng"
 ttp:cellResolution="50 30">
    <head>
        <styling>
            <style xml:id="spanStyle" tts:color="#000000" tts:backgroundColor="#00FF00" tts:fontSize="160%" tts:fontFamily="default"/>
            <style xml:id="paragraphStyle" tts:textAlign="center"/>
        </styling>
        <layout>
            <region xml:id="bottom" tts:origin="10% 10%" tts:extent="80% 80%" tts:displayAlign="after" />
        </layout>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p begin="00:00:00.000"  xml:id="p0" end="00:00:03.000" style="paragraphStyle" region="bottom">
                <span style="spanStyle">
     Example subtitle
    </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</tt>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't you need qualified tag names (i.e. including the namespaces) for those specialized elements?

Comment: The `xmlns` declaration on the `tt` element applies the namespace as the default so no extra namespace qualification is needed.

Comment: Although tt element is indeed  applied by default, I've tried adding it and result is still the same .

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code snippet that I can see at quick glance. If your question about applying external CSS then that's not supported by TTML. If your question is why are the `paragraphStyle` and `spanStyle` styles not being rendered correctly, I think that would be most likely due to incomplete implementation of TTML in IE - best option would be to raise an issue with Microsoft I think.

Comment: I think you're right about incomplete implementation of TTML in IE. Do you know some player that implements it, so I can try it?

Comment: If you want a complete reference implementation you should look at Skynav's TTT and [TTPE](https://github.com/skynav/ttt/) - other implementations implement varying levels of support, even the Flash video player supports some of TTML, as do older versions of IE. If you're interested in DASH packaging you could use the [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/) player too.

Comment: I've tried Skynav's TTT - (TTV and TPE) but the tool is not functional as I can see. At least not for adding new subtitle files. But I have found functional validator, now I just need player with full support.